# CSS - How to enable custom property in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Hello currently I'm learning CSS and I seeing CSS Custom property. I was trying to create a variable on VS-Code and run it using LiveServer but my variable doesn't seem work. Is there anything that I need to enable first in order to use CSS Variable on Chrome/Firefox? How to enable it? Thanks.

I'm using Firefox 68.9.0esr (32-bit) and Chrome 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

My css variable only like this:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&display=swap')
:root {
    --mistyrose: #ffe4e1;
    --blue: #118add;
    --green: #71cf17;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--mistyrose);

    /* center content */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
    border-right: 3px solid var(--blue);
    border-left: 3px solid var(--green);
}
```

Comment: Nope both browsers support variables out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **you missed a semicolon (`;`) in your `@import` statement** so your `:root` elements will be ignored and won't affect at all.

If you fix it, it should be something like this and your code will work well as expected:

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&display=swap');

:root {
  --mistyrose: #ffe4e1;
  --blue: #118add;
  --green: #71cf17;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--mistyrose);
  /* center content */
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
  border-right: 3px solid var(--blue);
  border-left: 3px solid var(--green);
}
```